# How to work json string on foreach loop in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach, warnings

I'm trying to make a foreach loop from string value which comes from a JSON value like:

```
string '["userdomain.ltd"], ["test.com"]'
```

I want to make a foreach loop and echo URL under the loop

I have tried using this but it returns PHP `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
foreach( $device_url as $url ){
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: This does not look like valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a string, so we need transform it to array for iterate:

```
<?php
$str = '["userdomain.ltd"], ["test.com"]';

$arr = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($arr as $el) {
    echo json_decode($el)[0];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Here you can try working code: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=17da273a4e6dd36288a67fcdeb8a0e92&sqlses=null&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you did not decode you string before passing it to your loop. And you can't loop on a string. You should use the `json_decode` function to decode it first, and then use your loop.

```
<?php
$input = '{"key": "value"}';
$decodedIntput = json_decode($input);
foreach( $decodedIntput as $url ){
    echo $url;
}
```

I did not used your json because it did not look valid.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your json string in square braces to make it valid before decoding it.  Then simply access the values in the first column of the 2d array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SSnbC))

```
var_export(
    array_column(json_decode("[$str]"), 0)
);
```